# XML difference using Maven

Tags: java, xml, diff, maven

I have a requirement to find out the differences between XML files of the current release and previous release, and report the differences in HTML format. These XML files are packaged in a jar during the build of their modules (in Maven), and are stored in our repository. I need to find and report differences during this Maven build process, and hence I am looking for a Maven plugin.

I found similar questions, but these are pretty old, and I was wondering if we have something latest:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617785/compare-xml-files-with-maven-or-ant
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375279/is-there-a-maven-plugin-that-can-diff-files-and-output-the-result-to-file

Is writing a Maven plugin with XMLUnit the best way to go with this? Do we have any Maven plugins?

Comment: I have in the past used BeyondCompare to perform such a task manually. It has features custom tailored to XML files that make it slightly easier to do it - still a lot of work. And no it does not generate HTML reports.

Answer (score -2):

To summarise, addressing your requirements:

1. Comparison of XML Files: Yes
2. Difference Report in HTML Output: Yes
3. Maven Plugin: No, but accessible via command line and APIs.

[XML Compare](https://www.deltaxml.com/products/compare/xml-compare/), developed by DeltaXML, is capable of producing a structurally aware XML diff output from two input files. Valid XML goes in, and valid XML comes out with the **changes identified by the addition of new attribute** that indicates whether the content or structure was present in the A input, present in the B input, and if it is the same in both or has changed.

Regarding your requirement for a **HTML output format**, there are multiple options available using XML Compare. Side-by-side and in-line change HTML diff reports can be produced with some of the pre-configured pipelines. If you need something in a more specific format, it is possible to configure your own outputs using XSLT, or by using other pre-configured options. You can see an example of the side-by-side output below:

[image]

Although there is **no Maven plugin** for XML Compare, it can be run via the **command line**, or via it's **REST and Java APIs**, meaning it can be easily integrated into other applications and workflows.

Disclosure: I am an employee of DeltaXML

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).